# How to bind an ICommand to TextBlock in Avalonia .net?

Tags: c#, .net, avaloniaui, avalonia

I am building a C# application using Avalonia MMVM.
On the left side of the application window, there should be a tree view of books grouped by genre. On the right side is a table with selected books. The user should be able to compile a list of books on the right side of those available on the left (preferably double click).
I'm trying to bind ICommand to TextBlock, but I don't understand how to do it correctly. Here is my MainWindow.axaml code:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding BookTree.Genres}">
        <TreeView.DataTemplates>
            <TreeDataTemplate DataType="models:Genre" ItemsSource="{Binding Books}">
                <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1"
                        CornerRadius="5" Padding="15 3">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </Border>
            </TreeDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="models:Book">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Author}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.DataTemplates>
    </TreeView>

    <DataGrid DockPanel.Dock="Right" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedBooks.SelectedBooks}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Title}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Author" Binding="{Binding Author}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</DockPanel>
```

I tried to add an additional button after the `<TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Author}"/>` line, but it is in a different datacontext. I also tried to add a SelectedItem to the `<TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Left" ItemsSource="{Binding BookTree.Genres}">` line, but I don't understand how to handle this event.

Just in case here is the MainWindowViewModel.cs code:

```
namespace SummerBooks.ViewModels
{
    public class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ICommand AddBookCommand { get; }
        public BookTreeViewModel BookTree { get; }
        public SelectedBooksViewModel SelectedBooks { get; }

        public MainWindowViewModel()
        {
            BookTree = new BookTreeViewModel();
            SelectedBooks = new SelectedBooksViewModel();
            AddBookCommand = ReactiveCommand.Create<Book>(book => 
            { 
                SelectedBooks.AddBook(book); 
            });
        }

    }

    public class BookTreeViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public SelectedBooksViewModel SelectedBooks { get; }
        public List<Genre> Genres { get; }

        public BookTreeViewModel()
        {
            Genres = new List<Genre>
            {
                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Fantastic",
                    Books = new List<Book>
                    {
                        new Book { Title = "1984", Author = "George Orwell"},
                        new Book { Title = "Solaris", Author = "Stanislav Lem"}
                    }
                },

                new Genre
                 {
                    Name = "Horror",
                    Books = new List<Book>
                    {
                        new Book { Title = "Ridges of Madness", Author = "Howard Lovecraft" },
                        new Book { Title = "Dreamcatcher", Author = "Stephen King" }
                    }
                },

                new Genre
                {
                    Name = "Fantasy",
                    Books = new List<Book>
                    {
                        new Book { Title = "Lord of the Rings", Author = "John Tolkien" },
                        new Book { Title = "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", Author = "Joanne Rowling" }
                    }
                }
            };

        }

    }

    public class SelectedBooksViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Book> SelectedBooks { get; }

        public SelectedBooksViewModel()
        {
            SelectedBooks = new ObservableCollection<Book>();
        }

        public void AddBook(Book book)
        {
            SelectedBooks.Add(book);
            //var box = MessageBoxManager.GetMessageBoxStandard("Caption", $"{SelectedBooks.Count}", MsBox.Avalonia.Enums.ButtonEnum.Ok);
            //box.ShowAsync();
        }
    }

}
```

Pls help :'(

Answer (score 0):

To handle an event the MVVM style, you should use Behaviors. Among other things, they sort of "translate" events into commands.
Import [Avalonia.Xaml.Behaviors](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia.Xaml.Behaviors) project from nuget, add namespaces to top control and add behavior to element. I have not tried this, but it should work within the binding context.

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity;assembly=Avalonia.Xaml.Interactivity"
xmlns:ia="clr-namespace:Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions.Core;assembly=Avalonia.Xaml.Interactions"


<TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding Author}"/>    
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <ia:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="DoubleTapped">
            <InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding AddBook}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </ia:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```